# Rails: Send Email notification to a company when user applies to a job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm working on a job board that have these relationships, a User can apply to many jobs, and jobs have many appliers (Users). A Company have many jobs.

User:

```
has_many :applications

has_many :jobs, :through => :applications, :uniq => true
```

Job

```
has_many :applications

has_many :users, :through => :applications
```

Application

```
 belongs_to :user 

 belongs_to :job
```

Company

```
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
```

I'd like to implement a feature that sends to the company an email when a user has applied to a job.

This is my mailer:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "email@gmail.com"

  def job_application(company)
    @company = company
    @job = job        
    @applications = @job.applications
    company = @job.application.company
    mail(to: @company.email, subject: 'Ha recibido una postulacion')
  end
end
```

Application.rb

```
after_create :send_email

def send_email
  NotificationMailer.job_application(self.company).deliver
end
```

obvioulsy I have some errors, what do I have to change or add to send the Company an email after the User applies to a Job?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move `after_create :send_email` and `send_email` method to Job model  because you want this email triggered when Job record is created *(ie. when User applies to job)*
2. Changes to send_email method (notice arguement self)

   > ```
   > def send_email
   >   NotificationMailer.job_application(self).deliver
   > end
   > ```
3. simplify your `NotificationMailer` method

   > ```
   > def job_application(job)
   >    @applications = job.applications
   >    mail(to: job.company.email, subject: 'Ha recibido una postulacion')
   > end
   > ```

Comment: thanks, but in development when a user applies to a jobs I got the error "undefined method `company' for #<Application:0xaac7150>" for the code in Application.rb

Comment: You are getting that because in application.rb, you reference self.company and since self is 'Application', it doesn't have a method called company. The real fix is to move this code into the Job model

Comment: I got the after_create :send_email and send_email method in Application.rb becuase I want the email triggered when the application is created, not the job, I made the changes you sugested, the user can apply to a job, but no email is send..